# Return an array of a field in c#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

What would be the equivalent of this code, but return all values (not only the distinct ones)?

```
    private List<string> GetDistinctValues(string field)
    {
        var collection = m_mongoDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("imageProperties");

        var filter = new BsonDocument();

        List<string> values = collection.Distinct<string>(field, filter).ToList();

        return values;
    }
```

Comment: Try replacing Distinct with Where.

Comment: @jdweng That is not valid syntax. Remember this in not a LINQ expression.

Comment: Did you try?  The Distinct is not a BsonDocument method either.  BsonDocument returns a IQueryable object that can be used be used by linq.

Comment: @jdweng Where is not a method on the collection object, so how can I try it when the compiler gives a syntax error?

Comment: You really have a Dictionary<string, List<object>> and the Distinct is get the unique value in the list.  So to get all : collection[field]

Comment: @jdweng "collection[field]" results in error "Error CS0021 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'IMongoCollection<BsonDocument>'"

Comment: See FindAs on following : https://mongodb-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver.html#gsc.tab=0